# How to send current page URL in a javascript object response?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to send the current page `URL` in a `js object` response. Whenever an `onclick` event will occur the location of the current page will be sent as an event.

```js
let ref = document.location.href;
```

```js
onclick="logEvent({fromURL: "'+ref+'"});"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attribute syntax is incorrect, you are treating an HTML attribute like if its a js expression. The contents inside the double quotes is javascript.

```
onclick="logEvent({fromURL: document.location.href});"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do

```
onclick="logEvent({fromURL: document.location.href});"
```